# how to make a custom calendar in android application?

Tags: android

I have to make an application with a calendar control built in for android 2.1-2.3.
I have tried to search for a inbuilt & external library to achieve this but have not been able to. 
Hence now i have decide to code the calendar myself. i was thinking of doing it via `GridView`. How do i go about this.

If there is a code available then do produce it over here. It would really be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/

Comment: Check this link may be usefull http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-simple-calender-in-gridview.html

Comment: guys someone needs to answer rather than commenting so that I can select a correct answer.

Comment: Both of those were completely custom... Since API level 11 there is a CalendarView available to use.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629314/my-program-hang-when-i-use-calendarview-in-my-activity/54996291#54996291

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend you take a look at the [Google Calendar](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) source. You may in fact just use their implementation. Using a GridView is also not bad. Android seems to also have a [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html). I would recommend looking at that, although I am not sure if its what you need. It would be helpful to know exactly what you need the calendar to do though. The question is very broad.

Comment: I want to implement features as Google calendars have. What would you recommend? Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find It is already completed, but when I was last use I added february 29 feature myself but it is good http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

Ancal is very good open source calendar to integrate and use in your code.
Code to this calendar can be check out from here:
https://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-simple-calender-in-gridview.html) is `good Custom Calender Example` for `SO user`.

I am using this calender in my **many project**.

If you have query then `put comment` otherwise accept answer.

Comment: why give me down rate please give me answer.This question is regarding custom calendar in android.

Answer (score 0):

you can use calendar API which is available from android 4.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

if your application has to be in android 2.0,you can add the android 4 library in your project.

i think its the easiest way to make your own custom calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Hi bro If your working on android web application means you can use jquery that will help you to make calender effectively or else you can look at this link may help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents